# firebase image upload and get image then i have to crop the firebase getting image

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire

I'm trying to upload image to firebase without croping and get the image to the app , util these it is working fine, now i want an crop option on displaying image to crop the image which is getting from firebase. using ionic2 and angular is it possible?

upload original image -> firebase -> display the uploaded image through firebase data -> now click on crop option -> crop the image using crop plugin and make it as profile pic

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by downloading image using ionic transfer file to device cache and redirecting the path to the local file and then use that path to crop the image.